# Stylish and beautiful screenshots of R code

Tags: r

I found several screenshots of R code like I show below, on Twitter and sometimes on Facebook. I wonder how people do it, because it can use also in Powerpoint or Beamer presentations. The code in the following screenshots are irrelevant for this question, I'm only wandering how to prepare or stylised those.

Thanks.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are usually generated via third-party services such as [Carbon](https://carbon.now.sh/). It's pretty straight-forward and you can customize all kinds of things like background color and code highlighting.

Feel free to check out their [About](https://carbon.now.sh/about) section and their [GitHub](https://github.com/carbon-app/carbon).